# How do you insert a query value as a parameter in sharepoint designer?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss, sharepoint-designer, xmlnode

I am trying to create a Data Source in SharePoint Designer that connects to a SharePoint List via XML Web Services.  I have created the Data Source and connected to the list in question.  I can view all the data using GetListItems, and I want to filter it using the query parameter.

The query parameter takes an XmlNode, and when I put this as the value I get an error:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Title" />
            <Value Type="Text">Foo</Value>
        </Eq>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

Of course, I have not entered any tabs or newlines, as I only have a one-line entry field in SharePoint Designer.  I receive an error with this query:

> The server returned a non-specific
>   error when trying to get data from the
>   data source. Check the format and
>   content of your query and try again. 
>   If the problem persists, contact the
>   server administrator.

I simply want to filter the list items resultset to be those with the Title field of "Foo".  Can this be done in SharePoint Designer?

---

Update: escaping the < and > in this manner also fails:

```
&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Title&quot; /&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;Text&quot;&gt;Foo&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;
```

---

Update: This appears to be a [known issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepointdesigner/archive/2008/06/20/data-source-issues-and-workarounds.aspx) with SoapDataSource components and SOAP calls.  Apparently, they are over-encoding the <'s and >'s before they get submitted.  The workaround given is to save the data source without a query parameter, and then to add it to the page and create a filter in the Common Data View Tasks dialog.  I was able to get this to work using the following filter string:

```
[@ows_Title = 'Foo']
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't help me much as I am adding a Data View (showing the data) rather than a DataSource that I can use to point other controls to (like a drop-down list).

I'm still looking for a good solution on this that lets me place a datasource using SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in SharePoint Designer.  You cannot pass a Query object to a SOAPDataSource like this - the XML gets overencoded.  Nothing you can do to fix it, except use Visual Studio.

I'll let you know if there's ever a hotfix available.

If anyone wants to quote this answer in a new answer, I'll accept that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you XML encode the query? I believe you need to encode characters like <, > and " such that it is valid XML, e.g. :

```
&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;
```

and

```
&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Title&quot; /&gt;
```

Comment: see my updates - apparently this is close to the problem, but the SoapDataSources munges the data.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, no, not yet at least. Haven't worked a lot with the SOAP data source.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://sharethelearning.blogspot.com/2009/03/building-query-web-service-call.html) shows how variables can be used to address a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Having worked with the list Title field, it does not return values for me unless I used "Contains".

This may not fix your error however.